# Using MongoDB's Geospatial features in Sails

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, sails.js, geospatial, waterline

I'd like to know if it's possible to make use of MongoDb's geo features from within Sails and Waterline.

Basically I'll need to query for property listings that are within say, a 5 Km radius of some location [x, y]
Using Mongoose, I'd do the following:

```
var area = { center: [5.23, 1.9], radius: 5, unique: true, spherical: true };

var query = Property.find();

query
  .where('location')
  .within()
  .circle(area)
  .populate('owner', 'name image')
  .execAsync()
  .then(function (listings){
    // respond
  }
```

Where location is type array with longitude and latitude.

How can I do this in waterline. If it's not possible what are the options available. I have seen that some people have been able to disable waterline and use mongoose or other orms, but it seems hacky and moreover you might lose out on the sails' blueprints feature, I think. Maybe trails? Changing orms seems to be inbuilt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible by waterline, but you can always use .native query: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/waterline/models/native.md

Comment: Thanks. any idea how I can achieve 2dsphere indexing?

Comment: Never worked with it sorry :( Maybe this could help? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/